# How to write a Windows Batch Script to Move files and delete on same script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

H,

I need to create a script to run as a pre-script on our Backup schedule to first move files to a destination folder and delete files older than x days on that dessication folder.

I know I can use Robocopy and forfiles to create separate tasks but i need to run it on the same script..

eg:-

move files in c:\Backup\ to D:\Old_Backup and search for files older than 3 days on D:\Old_Backup and delete them from D:\Old_Backup folder.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't get it. Why can't you use a robocopy to copy the files and a for loop with remove-item command foreach old files in the same script?

Comment: I'm new to scripting.. i just managed to do it by following test script i tested with.

robocopy "d:\source" "d:\Delete" /mov
forfiles /p "d:\Delete"  /m *.inf /D -365 /c "cmd /c del @path"

It would be great if you can let me know another way so I can improve my self...

Comment: The two commands should work fine when on separate lines - just don't call the batch file `robocopy` or `forfiles` because it won't work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to help you to improve, I just do not understand your question.

If you want to write script for Windows I encourage you to learn how to use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

As you describe it, I do not see any reason why you cannot writes it in a single script. Thus my supposition is that maybe it is not clear for you what a [script](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/script.html) exactly is.

You can write several commands line in your script, thus it should be easy to write a script moving required files and deleting other required files in the same script.

Edit: you will find all required ressources [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/benp/archive/2009/12/02/powershell-resources.aspx).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the support. I'll try to read some article on Powershell. 

AS you mentioned I was able to write whole set of commands on the same script. I though it will not work.. 

Thanks again for the support. If you could please let me know few sites or books that i can refer to improve in PowerShell.